# form.formGroup.value is different to console.log(form)

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-forms

I have a problem. I emit a Form to a compoenent.

If i use a console.log(form) it gives me the object. If i look at the object in the console the form.formGroup.value looks fine (like `{MOBILE0: 'xxx', PHONE0: 'xxx', EMAIL0: 'xxx'}`.

But if i use console.log(form.formGroup.value) the value in the console locks like that `{PHONE0: 'xxx', EMAIL0: 'xxx'}`.

Why is the value different to the normal form?

Have somone a short solution for me?

Comment: form is different from `form.value` so what do you expect in `console.log()` ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Ramesh i expect that the console.log(form.formGroup.value) gives me `{MOBILE0: 'xxx', PHONE0: 'xxx', EMAIL0: 'xxx'}` and not without the MOBILE0

Comment: must be form.value.formGroup or form.get('formGroup').value

Comment: @Fl4mer post your code related to the form or a stackBlitz resembling your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it right now it was a Bug on a other Code Line